# Getting 404 for only some WebAPI methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I just added two methods to one of my WebAPI controllers today that are intended to used with GETs. I already had one such method in the controller and it works perfectly fine, so I know it can't be a routing issue in that sense.

The following is my webapiconfig.cs:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "MiscellaneousApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/misc/{action}",
    defaults: new {controller = "miscellaneousapi"});
```

The following is the simplified declaration of both the working method (GetFoo) and the 404 method (GetBar):

```
namespace MyControllers {
  public class MiscellaneousApiController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetFoo")
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFoo()
    {
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetBar")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetBar()
    {
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
  }
}
```

As I said, it works fine for the GetFoo method.

I've added GetBar and when I put in the URL into either my browser or Fiddler, I get a 404. I attempted to put the methods in another controller and got 404s there as well. What's going on? Why does the GetFoo work fine and GetBar utterly fails? There's functionally no difference between the two of them. I could understand if it were a non-404 error that there was something wrong with the logic inside, but it's a 404 I'm receiving.

And yes, I have double checked that I'm typing in the url correctly, each is decorated with [HttpGet] and neither one accepts any parameters. Thanks!

Comment: do you have any parameters on the `GetBar` action..can you share how it looks like?

Comment: Can you please post your `GetFoo` and `GetBar` declarations along with all their decorations?

Answer (score 2):

I'm honestly surprised you're not getting a 404 for both of them.  Do you have any other routes defined and/or is GetFoo declared elsewhere as well?

The issue I see here is that you're defining a default value for `{controller}`, but that placeholder isn't used in your route.  Instead, you're trying to set it to `misc` and your controller class is named `MiscellaneousApiController`. Does it work if you change your route template to `api/miscellaneousapi/{action}`?

Comment: If I set the route template to api/miscellaneousapi/{action}, either one of the methods now yields a 500. I set a breakpoint in each one to see if it was a result of the method, but neither ever gets hit.

Comment: Strangely, upon reverting the change to the route template, each of the functions now works as expected. That's bizarre to me as I cleaned and rebuilt the solution before posting this question, but it's working now with api/misc/{action} and GetFoo() and GetBar().

Comment: That's definitely strange.  Glad it's working now, though.